# How do I enable read and write permissions to group calendars in Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016, microsoft-teams

How do I enable read and write permissions to group calendars in Office 365 for everyone in the group? A group created in Outlook and then turned into a Team has what should be a shared calendar, but it can only be read (show's Busy) or edited (not possible at all) in the creators (me - and I'm a global admin) Outlook and machine. And not even the creator has access to the calendar on another machine.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you created a group in Outlook, what's the group type? A contact group or an Office 365 group?

If it's the later one, you could connect to Exchange Online PowerShell, then run the following command to grant group members editor permission to the group calendar one by one.

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity groupname@contoso.com:\Calendar -User username@contoso.com -AccessRights Editor

Comment: It's an Office 365 group according to the admin panel. I tried the command you suggested and get "The specified mailbox .... doesn't exist". I triple checked that I used the correct value.

Comment: Try the following commands to set the read-only permissions. 

1. Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell with an Office 365 admin account.

2. Run this command to set the read-only value:

Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity *** Email address is removed for privacy *** -CalendarMemberReadOnly

3. Run this command to check the CalendarMemberReadOnly in this group.

Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity *** Email address is removed for privacy *** -IncludeAllProperties | Format-List

Note: Replace *** Email address is removed for privacy *** to your Office 365 group’s email address.